# GRUB2: unknown filesystem for all partitions

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have 5 partitions on my SSD.

```
1 - ?
2 - Windows
3 - ?
4 - EFI System
5 - Ubuntu
```

I was out of space on 5th partition so i decided to boot from LiveCD and expand it. I took some space from 1st partition and positioned it right after 5th partition. Then i expanded 5th partition. Everything worked out fine and i was able to use both systems.

Today grub2 did not boot. It boots only in grub rescue. I tried to find a partition with Ubuntu through the ls command but i got "unknown filesystem" for every partition. Then I booted from LiveCD and used Boot-Repair - it didn't help. Also I opened gparted - there is also a "unknown filesystem" statement for every partition except Windows partition, I guess because i didn't move it. Secure boot option is disabled.

Asking for help since I can't figure it out by myself.

Comment: Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair.